# Search on multiple fields with Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch and I'm wondering how I can make a search specifing one or more fields.

With SQL I would write this query:

```
"SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM tablename WHERE field1 = 'X' AND field2 != 'Y' AND field3 = 'Z'"
```

In Elasticsearch I'm starting from this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "*"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term" : {
                    "field1" : "286"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to pick the right query for the job, which can be hard in the beginning. You can definitely use a bool query to combine all sorts of different queries together, like already suggested. There are also queries that allow to be executed on multiple fields, and map to boolean queries internally. Also, [term queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/term-query/) are not so common in a production system since they don't support any text analysis, while you usually want to analyze the query in a way that's similar to the way you indexed the field you are querying.

One of the most common queries in elasticsearch is the match query, which works on a single field. And there's another query with the very same options that works also on multiple fields, called [multi_match](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/multi-match-query/). These queries support text analysis and work really well. I would suggest to use them over query_string query for instance, which is a lot more powerful but error-prone as well due to the needed parsing process. I would say use the query_string only if you specifically need one of its features (e.g. specifying the field names or boolean operators within the query itself), otherwise go for match queries.

It's also important to understand the difference between queries and filters, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595988/queries-vs-filters) to know more.

And do have a look at all the queries available with [the query DSL](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/) and play around with those, just to have a feeling of all the different things you can do.

Comment: Aside from being well written, this post was incredibly helpful. Thank you for your explanation and linking to sources.

Comment: How would you combine `multi_match` with `match_phrase_prefix`? I want to search for a substring in multiple fields. It doesn't have to match all fields, as long as it exists in one of them.

Comment: Updated links: [term queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) , [multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) , [the query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html)

Answer (score 40):

The sql query is equivalent to:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "field1": "X"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "field3": "Z"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": {
        "term": {
          "field2": "Y"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In any case I recommend you to read a bit the doc before starting with elasticsearch if you are new.

There are lots of types of queries and some of them depends on how you index your data, for example for strings, you can analyze strings (lowercase, stem words, remove stopwords, ...) at index time. The query I posted will never match a doc whose field1 is "X" if you analyze that field at index time and convert it to lower case.

Once you know a little bit better elasticsearch you can use filters for improving your queries.

Comment: What if I wanted to search field1 for "X" and "Q"? I tired something like: "field1": ["X","Q"] but didn't work

Comment: @codeBarer use terms query instead of term query. Look at this => http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Comment: I believe instead of term, you can use match as well!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search same value on multiple fields then you can try

```
{"query": {"multi_match": {"query": "querystring", "fields": ["name", "description"]}}}
```

Replace `querystring` with your search keyword

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start with Elastic's Simple query. It's more SQL-like and easier to understand. Link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html

Query syntax will look like, e.g. if you're trying to find guest with name John AND lastname Doe:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "John + Doe",
        "fields": ["guest"],
        "default_operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```

If any of this criterias will not match, query will return no hits. Also, here you can search over multiple fields, but it will be slower rather than searching on one field. Also, per docs, simple query support special symbols as logical\search operators:

```
 '+' signifies AND operation | signifies OR operation
 '-' negates a single token " wraps a number of tokens to signify a phrase for searching
 '*' at the end of a term signifies a prefix query
```