# Full text search exact match with multiple fields on querystring

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch Mapping

"name" : {
"type" : "text",
"fields" : {
"keyword" : {
"type" : "keyword",
"ignore_above" : 256
},
"normalizer" : {
"type" : "keyword",
"normalizer" : "lowercase_normalizer"
}
}
},

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search on multiple fields with Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695310/search-on-multiple-fields-with-elasticsearch)

Comment: @Venkat can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?