# Elasticsearch for logging - need architectural advice

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to come up with an optimized architecture to store event logging messages on Elasticsearch.

Here are my specs/needs:

- Messages are read-only; once entered, they are only queried for reporting.
- No free text search. User will use only filters for reporting.
- Must be able to do `timestamp` range queries.
- Mainly need to filter by `agent` and `customer` interactions (in addition to other fields).
- `customers` and `agents` belong to the same `location`.

So the most frequently executed query will be: get all `LogItem`s given `client_id`, `customer_id`, and `timestamp` range.

Here is what a `LogItem` looks like:

```
"_source": {
    "agent_id" : 14,
    "location_id" : 2,
    "customer_id" : 5289,
    "timestamp" : 1320366520000, //Java Long millis since epoch
    "event_type" : 7,
    "screen_id" : 12
}
```

I need help indexing my data.

I have been reading [what is an elasticsearch index?](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/what-is-an-elasticsearch-index/) and [using elasticsearch to serve events for customers](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/using-elasticsearch-and-logstash-to-serve-billions-of-searchable-events-for-customers/) to get an idea of a good indexing architecture, but I need assistance from the pros.

So here are my questions:

1. The article suggests creating "One index per day". **How would I do range queries with that architecture?** (eg: is it possible to query on index range?)
2. Currently I'm using one big index. **If I create one index per location_id, how do I use shards for further organization of my records?**
3. Given the specs above, **is there a better architecture you can suggest?**
4. What fields should I **filter** with vs **query** with?

**EDIT**: Here's a sample query run from my app:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [ {
        "term" : {
          "agent_id" : 6
        }
      }, {
        "range" : {
          "timestamp" : {
            "from" : 1380610800000,
            "to" : 1381301940000,
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true
          }
        }
      }, {
        "terms" : {
          "event_type" : [ 4, 7, 11 ]
        }
      } ]
    }
  },
  "filter" : {
    "term" : {
      "customer_id" : 56241
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely search on multiple indices. You can use wildcards or a comma-separated list of indices for instance, but keep in mind that index names are strings, not dates.

Shards are not for organizing your data but to distribute it and eventually scale out. How you do that is driven by your data and what you do with it. Have a look at this talk: http://vimeo.com/44716955 .

Regarding your question about filters VS queries, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595988/queries-vs-filters) other question.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I understand your point about indices being strings, so I shall reconsider. I asked about shards because the article about logging in my question said "Of course each these could be split up further by sharding on, for example, the event type, if needed." Can I explicitly define something like that? Also, my messages are read only once indexed, so is there any form of optimization I can do? Thank you

Comment: You can somehow manually shard docs if you want, using routing. THen you would send documents with same routing value always to the same shards (but different values might end up in the same shard). Anyways, I'd consider routing an advanced feature, not something to start with. Have a look at this talk: http://vimeo.com/44716955 .

Comment: I've been reading your answers to Elasticsearch posts, and they are very informative! I watched your video and did more research and I have come up with the following architecture: Since `customers` and `agents` belong to the same `location`, I would make an index per `location`. I was thinking of setting up routing per `agent`. `Locations` usually have ~30 `agents`, except for one that has 252. In addition to that, I would use the standard (5 shards,1 replica) per index. I would appreciate your feedback on this structure.

Answer (score 1):

Take a good look at logstash (and kibana). They are all about solving this problem. If you decide to roll your own architecture for this, you might copy some of their design.