# ElasticSearch: Perform a simple IN query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to ElasticSearch, trying to learn it.

In a regular RDBM, I can perform an "in" statement as follows:

```
 select * from results where mycal in ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'] and col2 in ['er', 'es', 'et']
```

How do I do this in elasticsearch?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot would depend on how you index the data in elasticsearch. But you could use the  [terms filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) to achieve the above:

```
  {
   "filter": {
      "and": [
         {
            "terms": {
               "cal": [
                  "abc",
                  "def",
                  "ghi"
               ],
               "execution": "or"
            }
         },
         {
            "terms": {
               "col2": [
                  "er",
                  "es",
                  "et"
               ],
               "execution": "or"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 for Filters, they're faster than queries, cached for fast responses. Baring in mind that Elasticsearch does not score filter results.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you want a [filter or a query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14600680/706724), you can go use either the [`bool`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query/filter or the shortcut [`terms`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) query/filter (both linked to the query, as I expect this will not want to be cached).

As you are going with more than one field, then you want to use the `bool` query using `terms` within it:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        { "terms" : { "mycal" : [ "abc", "def", "ghi" ] } },
        { "terms" : { "col2" : [ "er", "es", "et" ] } }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 2
    }
  }
}
```

By default, `"minimum_should_match"` will be `1`, which would make the above query an `OR`.

This assumes documents like:

```
{ "mycal" : "abc", "col2" : "es" }
{ "mycal" : "def", "col2" : "er" }
```

If your fields were nested within an object (e.g., `{ "key" : { "mycal" : "abc" } }`), then you would just access them like `"key.mycal"`.

The important part is how you do your mapping. By default, your string will be analyzed and stored in all lowercase, and therefore you need to search using the `term`(s) query in all lowercase. If you wanted to find `"ABC"`, then you would *still* look for `"abc"`. However, if you used something else, like `match` instead of `term`(s), then you do not need to put it in all lowercase:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        { "match" : { "mycal" : "ABC" } },
        { "match" : { "mycal" : "DEF" } },
        { "match" : { "mycal" : "GHI" } },
        { "match" : { "col2" : "ER" } },
        { "match" : { "col2" : "ES" } },
        { "match" : { "col2" : "ET" } }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 2
    }
  }
}
```