# Elasticsearch: performance in case of complex filters and lot of records

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. I need to build a query with querying (scoring) on two text fields plus complex filters. Here is what I got so far (with the help of kind folks such as Dan Tuffery, John Petrone, and dark_shadow at SO) and it works:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "or": [
      {
        "and": [
          {
            "range": {
              "start": {
                "lte": 201407292300
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "end": {
                "gte": 201407292300
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "condtion1": false
            }
          },
          {
            "or": [
              {
                "and": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "condtion2": false
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "or": [
                      {
                        "and": [
                          {
                            "missing": {
                              "field": "condtion6"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "missing": {
                              "field": "condtion7"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "condtion6": "nop"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "condtion7": "rst"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "and": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "condtion2": true
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "or": [
                      {
                        "and": [
                          {
                            "missing": {
                              "field": "condtion3"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "missing": {
                              "field": "condtion4"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "missing": {
                              "field": "condtion5"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "missing": {
                              "field": "condtion6"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "missing": {
                              "field": "condtion7"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "condtion3": "abc"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "condtion4": "def"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "condtion5": "ghj"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "condtion6": "nop"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "condtion7": "rst"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "and": [
          {
            "term": {
              "condtion8": "TIME_POINT_1"
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "start": {
                "lte": 201407302300
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "or": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "condtion9": "GROUP_B"
                }
              },
              {
                "and": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "condtion9": "GROUP_A"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "ids": {
                      "values": [
                        100,
                        10
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "and": [
          {
            "term": {
              "condtion8": "TIME_POINT_2"
            }
          },
          {
            "ids": {
              "values": [
                100,
                10
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "and": [
          {
            "term": {
              "condtion8": "TIME_POINT_3"
            }
          },
          {
            "or": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "condtion1": true
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "end": {
                    "lt": 201407302300
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "or": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "condtion9": "GROUP_B"
                }
              },
              {
                "and": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "condtion9": "GROUP_A"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "ids": {
                      "values": [
                        100,
                        10
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am wondering whether Elasticsearch will perform well in case of such queries against hundreds of thousands of records.

Basically I am facing choice of technologies. I am thinking about whether traditional database plus full-text search features do a better job. I do like what Elasticsearch offers and the features to use possibly in my project  in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you are using a lot of AND/OR/NOT Filters. I strongly recommend going through these links:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/filter-caching.html
http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/

you should use **bool filter instead of And/Or/Not** as bool filter are internally cached. So, its much faster. Also, you are using term and missing filter which are inherently fast as they operate on terms level.

A last advise would be to properly analyze your use case and better approach your problem. Try to reduce number of filters by making effective choices. ElasticSearch can handle these filters very well and with caching it won't be too slow.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for helping me again! I will seriously look into using bool filter. One quick question:  The filters in my query are built dynamically for each user: some filters are fixed, some are changing for each user. In this case, caching will help regarding fixed filters, correct? How to create "OR" through bool filters? Thanks again for showing me the right direction!!!

Comment: Yes, bool filter works with dynamic values also. The way caching is implemented is actually using bitset which is way more faster. Try using bool should for OR operator.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i think elastic search will be a good choice of technology for what you are trying to achieve, i have used FAST, Solr and SQL in the past, but i really find ES much better.

Do have a look at this [Queries vs. Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595988/queries-vs-filters) as its important to know when to use filters vs queries, as elastic search does some caching.

I have ran complex histograms over 800 million records on one server (16 cores, 64GB Ram, 500GB SAN) and it works very well, i would prefer to cluster the instance however my client does not wish to add a couple of more linux servers (madness really). You should ideally set ES up with 3 nodes as this gives you great performance and high availability, which i have done at another clients setup and works a dream.

Comment: Lee, thanks so much for chiming in. I was thinking about moving some filters into query part. However, I dont know how to completely disable the scoring on filter-turned-query matches. Again, thanks!