# Elastic(search): How to structure nested queries correctly?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently quite confuse about the structuring of queries in elastic. Let me explain what I mean with the following template that works fine for me:

```
{
"template" : {
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        { "match" : {
                            "user"  : "{{param_user}}"
                        } },
                        { "match" : {
                            "session" : "{{param_session}}"
                        } },
                        { "range" : {
                            "date" : {
                                "gte" : "{{param_from}}",
                                "lte" : "{{param_to}}"
                            }
                        } }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Ok so I want to get entries of a specific session of a user in a certain time period. Now if you take a llok at this link http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html you can find the following query:

```
{
"query" : {
  "filtered" : { 
     "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : [
             { "term" : {"price" : 20}}, 
             { "term" : {"productID" : "XHDK-A-1293-#fJ3"}} 
          ],
          "must_not" : {
             "term" : {"price" : 30} 
          }
       }
     }
  }
}
}
```

In this example we have right after the `"filtered"` the `"filter"` keyword. However if I exchange my second `"query"` with a `"filter"` as in the example , my template won't work anymore. This is really counterintuitive and I payed alot of time to figure this out. A̶l̶s̶o̶ ̶I̶ ̶d̶o̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶u̶n̶d̶e̶r̶s̶t̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶w̶h̶y̶ ̶w̶e̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶p̶u̶t̶ ̶e̶v̶e̶r̶y̶ ̶f̶i̶l̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶s̶e̶p̶a̶r̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶`̶{̶ ̶}̶`̶ ̶e̶v̶e̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶o̶u̶g̶h̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶y̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶a̶l̶r̶e̶a̶d̶y̶ ̶s̶e̶p̶a̶r̶a̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶b̶y̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶a̶r̶r̶a̶y̶ ̶s̶y̶n̶t̶a̶x̶.̶

Another issue I had was that I suggested to match several fields I can just type smth like:

```
{
"query" : {
    "match" : {
        "user"  : "{{param_user}}",
        "session" : "{{param_session}}"
    }
}
}
```

but it seemed that I have to use a bool query which I didn't know of, so I searched for 'elastic multi match' but got something completely different.

My question: where can I find how to structure a query properly (smth like a PEG)? The documentation only give basic examples but doesn't state what we can actually do and how.

Best regards,
Jan

**Edit:** Ok I just found by accident that I cannot exchange `"query"` with `"filter"` as `"match"` is a query and not a filter. But then again what about `"range"`? It seems to be a query as well as a filter... Is there a summary of keywords specifying in which context they can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a summary of keywords specifying in which context they can be used?

I wouldn't consider that as `keywords`. It's just there are both queries and filters with the same names (but not all of them).

[Here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl.html) is everything you need. For example there are both `range` query and filter. All you need is to understand the difference between filters and queries.

For example, if you want to move `range` section from query to filter, you can do that like shown in the code below (not tested). Since your code already contains `filtered` type of query, you can just create `filter` section right after `query` section.

```
{
    "template": {
        "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "user": "{{param_user}}"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "session": "{{param_session}}"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "range": {
                        "date": {
                            "gte": "{{param_from}}",
                            "lte": "{{param_to}}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just remember that you can filter only **not** analyzed fields.

Comment: Well this makes alot more sense. I didn't understand the difference between filter and query well. Helped me alot but I'm afraid your link is broke ;)

Comment: Fixed. Just didn't actually copied the link :P Anyway  it's just Elasticsearch docs. ;-) You can see the queries and filters available there. Once you'll get the idea of nesting queries/filters, it becomes super easy to use.

Comment: Yes I see. So the idea is to use queries to reduce size of fetched documents (only the relevant) and the filters are then used to narrow them even further depending on what a user want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595988/queries-vs-filters this should help. Also filters can be considered as something similar to casual `WHERE` clause in SQL, while the query is about full text searching.