# Get data from elastic search using URL queries without using NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I want to perform 4 `filter search` operations namely `equal`,`greaterthan`,`lessthan` and `contains` in elasticsearch data **without** using `NEST` and queries sent over `HttpRequest.WebRequest`.

When i googled i found in one post that URL query has limitation. Can anyone help me out . If its not possible can you provide me a URL or example on how to execute by passing the query as JSON over HttpRequest

Comment: I see that query  & filters though performs same functionality has performance difference. Now i am confused. Say i want to query list of employees whose Age is 29 , Name contains aplhabet "A", Job is in IT,Salary greater than 10k and salary less than 20k . Which one shall i use then ?? A Query/filter

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595988/queries-vs-filters) provides some clues. Though, you should note that as of ES 2.0 queries and filters [have been merged together](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html#_queries_and_filters_merged)

Comment: Thanks for the link val. In the official site, they have given examples that can be run in CURL. What if we are to implement using webrequest. Say i connect to URL, send query as data over stream. I tried the query in REST client and response is showing it created, rather than fetching data

Comment: this is the URL : http://localhost:9200/testentity/TestDoc/ and this is the query i used as body as POST method
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": { 
      "query": {
        "match": { "tweet": "full text search" }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": { "created": { "gte": "now-1d/d" }}
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: response i got 
{
"_index": "testentity"
"_type": "TestDoc"
"_id": "AVG_IutNbD06ETf1AsKv"
"_version": 1
"_shards": {
"total": 2
"successful": 1
"failed": 0
}-
"created": true
}

Comment: You need to POST your query to the `localhost:9200/testentity/TestDoc/_search` endpoint, otherwise you're just creating a new document.

Comment: Yeah that was the thing missing :P. Thanks val...